# Applied Machine Learning Max_Iter

Tags: machine-learning, epoch

[image: Machine]

Question the following diagram shows loss values as a function of epochs during training. if you had to rerun the experiment, what value would you use for maxiter and why?

Answer (score 0):

When rerunning the experiment you would look at using a larger number of epochs (max_iter). We can see that the loss is being minimised but has not fully converged. Its hard to judge from the graph but I would try 100 epochs and iterate based on results.